# Problem with the alexbruy repository with plugins for QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, repository, whitebox-tools

I have tried to install some of the QGIS plugins in the alexbruy repository https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml, but for each plugin get the following message:

`Plugin installation failed: Error transferring https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/processing_wbt.zip - server replied: Not Found`

I want to install the White box Tools for Processing plugin following the user manual at: "https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/qgis_plugin.html", but I can't make it work (QGIS 3.16 and 3.18).

Does anyone have any ideas on this problem?

Comment: As you have already written the question on the github in the author's repository, you have to wait for his reactions. additionally, you can download the repository from github and install the plugin from a zip file.

Comment: Yes, I have asked in the author's repository but I have not received an answer. Regarding the installation from the zip I am not sure how to carry it out, for this reason I have only considered doing it from the repository. Do you have any ideas on how I can install it directly from the archives on Github?

Comment: Just download zip file and point QGIS to this file.

Comment: The only zip file that can be downloaded is in the GitHub repository and it is not recognized by QGIS as a valid plugin. I do not know how to install it from this source, if you know how to do it, I would appreciate your comment.

Comment: Alex Bruy is Ucranian, https://plugins.bruy.me is down because of the *WAR* in Ucraine (evil people want us to call it a "military operation"). Good luck to all ucranian people!